# Setup Ubuntu with Apache to redirect subdomains to other internal ip's and different ports

Tags: networking, ssh, apache2

I have been trying to hours to get this to work with zero luck.

What I'm trying to do is setup so that if I `ssh` to `something.domain.com` apache will redirect to a different internal ip like `192.168.0.17:22`

I've done this before with only port 80 open on my router.

Like I had `domain.com` as my website, I had `music.domain.com` redirecting to a different internal ip and port for Subsonic and `servername.domain.com` redirecting to a Windows machine for RDP.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! This seems like a DNS issue. Have you tried looking up how to do DNS and router port forwarding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `ssh` goes to port 22 on the server unless the client is reconfigured to use some other port, either with `-p port` on the command line, or with a more permanent setting in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. I will assume you have got that sorted, so that your `ssh something.domain.com` goes to port 80 on the server (well, on the router, which presumably is set up to forward it to the server).

Next, (and now I've learnt something new), you adapt and apply the instructions from http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssl-single-443.html

That is, you download and run that `connect_switch` perl script, which is the connection dispatcher based on targeted host name.